# Resultant running too slow

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials

I have a system of equations all linear in one variable X with many parameters. I am trying to separate the variable in these equations by taking the pairwise resultants of one of the equation with the other ones so that the resultants are equal. E.g.

```
A1=Resultant[eq1,eq2,X];
A2=Resultant[eq1,eq3,X];
...
An=Resultant[eq1,eqn,X];
```

Where the equations are something like this:

```
eq1 = a b c X +  e/h f^5 g^2 X + 6 a^3/g k X + .... + az/h^2 X
 .....
```

And what I want to get are expressions `A1,..An` in `a, b, c,..` (free of X), which are equal.
However, it is running too slow and I am not getting any result. Perhaps there is another way of doing that in Mathematica?

Comment: This is hard to answer without concrete definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that using `Solve` is much faster than `Resultant`. So if I solve each equation for `X`, I get equal expressions in `a, b, c`, etc free of `X` as required.